# SSRS Report only returns a single row of output instead of multiple pages of output

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, grid, reporting, ssrs-2012

I am looking to build a report in SSRS that has 3 columns, similar to the data below.
The query behind the report returns a single row for every field in the 3 columns.

[image]

The report returns 20 rows for example, with 50 fields each pertaining to the elements outlined below.

However when I view the report I only see the first rows output. I need to create the elements in very particular positions and don't want to use tables and concatenate fields. I need a flat report 8.5 x 11 with elements in specific positions.

How do I fix the grouping so the report returns every row sent from the query.

There is no table, no groups. Only a single page with elements on it.
[image]

Please advise.

Comment: Are these text boxes in a table? I'm guessing this is one big table cell. It sounds like you are grouping the table data when you don't want a group. Show the tables design view with the table top-left corner selected so it shows the grouping on the left (lines like = or { ).

Comment: Hello @HannoverFist, I updated the question. We have one big cell. No tables, no groups. If i build a table how do i allow the flexibility of adding these elements exactly where i want them.